# How can I get a backup of my Gmail and Yahoo mails to my PC?

Tags: windows-xp, backup, gmail, yahoo-mail

Is there a way to backup all mails of my Gmail and Yahoo mails to my local computer...
I don't use Outlook...

- How can I get a backup my Gmail and Yahoo mails to my PC?

Any ways...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For backing up Gmail I like to use [Gmail Backup](http://www.gmail-backup.com/). I also use it to archive email from ex-employees in our Google Apps account.

Another option for Gmail is to use any IMAP capable mail program to pull everything. Thunderbird is often suggested. See Lifehacker's "[Backing up Gmail with Thunderbird](http://lifehacker.com/234717/backing-up-gmail-with-thunderbird)" article.

Afraid I don't have any ideas for Yahoo... do they still only offer IMAP to paid accounts?

Answer (score 3):

For Yahoo Mail, you can use [Zimbra Desktop](http://www.zimbra.com/products/desktop.html) to get all mails from all folders. You don't even need Yahoo Mail Plus, as Zimbra must be acting as a browser and not a pop client (for which you'd only be able to get Inbox).

I just learned it myself from a [PC Mech article](http://www.pcmech.com/article/how-to-get-a-complete-yahoo-mail-backup-with-zimbra-desktop/), which is probably based on an earlier version of Zimbra Desktop. I just downloaded 2.0.1b10659, and Import/Export is an item under a mail account after you click the Preferences tab.

Comment: +1. Thanks for this hidden gem and explaining important caveats. I should back up a few thousand e-mails before Yahoo breaks that compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

[MailStore](http://www.mailstore.com/en/mailstore-home.aspx). For Gmail, you can use IMAP to backup your email. For Yahoo, I think you'd need to have their premium service in order to get IMAP or POP3 access.

Answer (score 0):

The freeware listed above "gmail backup" has now some problems as it change unread messages as read ! ;( 
Personally I recommend backupgoo (not freeware) http://alternativeto.net/software/backupgoo/

Answer (score 0):

2 years later update : I now use spanning backup : 
I can export all my Gmail emails at once  or only emails for a specific date period.

Note: The export is a ".MBOX" format (as a zip file). Then I use the freeware MBOX Converter http://www.aid4mail.com/mbox-converter.php in order to convert the ".mbox" file into ".eml" files.

You can subscribe here http://spanning.com/ 
(or you and I can get a $5 rebate if you use this link : https://spanningbackup.com/s5m5/A7E6XK )